# Add checkbox in span in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, checkbox

How to add checkbox in span in reactjs for mobileApp. find code below:

i want to add style in checkbox like want to reduce font-size and width. How should i add css in this code?

```
<ul data-role="listview">
              <li><input type="checkbox"/><a href="#"><span> <i className="fa fa-edit"></i></span><span className="case-overflow"> Case11</span></a></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox"/><a href="#"><span> <i className="fa fa-edit"></i></span><span className="case-overflow"> Case12</span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: what is your question actually ? You ask how to include css file to your project ? I can see in your example you arr allready adding classes to "fa fa-edit" ect. so I assume you understand how className works, right ?

Comment: I want to add css for checkbox i.e. margin:0 . I have used below code:                <li><input style={checoboxStyle} type="checkbox"/>..       here i am using checkboxStyle as variable and defined in javascript.                                                    var checoboxStyle = {
    margin:0
   };  but it is not working

Comment: is it typo ? checoboxStyle != checkboxStyle

Answer (score 0):

To add css class for checkbox element use `className` keyword

```
<input type="checkbox" className="margin-zero"/>
```

Note that class `.margin-zero` has to be included before in layout of your project.

If you want to add specific style in one place you can define it like this

```
var checkboxStyle = {
  margin: 0
};
```

Note that when specifying a pixel value for your inline style prop, React automatically appends the string "px" for you after your number value.

To use yor new style in render write:

```
<input type="checkbox" style={checkboxStyle}/>
```

Comment: if i want to add checkbox inside a link, it is clickable.

Comment: <ul data-role="listview">
       <li><a className={statusClass} href="pages/caseDetails.html"><input style={checoboxStyle} type="checkbox"/><span> <i className="fa fa-edit"></i></span><span className="case-overflow"> Case12</span></a></li
      </ul>

Comment: I only showed you how to apply style, clickable link is a diffrent story, and as I can see you know how to implement it...